# Yii: Server issues controller action always 404 not found

Tags: php, yii, lamp

I am currently developing my website app and I need to test it on live server.

On local machine it was working well however on live server it does not work.

Here is my problem description:

```
When I access the domain root folder "mydomain.com" it is working. 
It displays the
webpage index. But when I try to access site/action it 
gives me 404 not found. Same thing happens for other controller action.
```

can anybody tell me what is wrong..I am not expert with live server so I am not good in terminologies I can only describe what is happening.

I am not sure if this is worth mentioning but I am using the yii urlManager

with this settings

```
'urlManager'=>array(
            'urlFormat'=>'path',
            'rules'=>array(
                '<action:\w+>' => 'site/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            ),
            'showScriptName'=>false
        ),
```

and an htaccess on root folder..

server is : LAMP

Thanks alot for your help.. Everyone is appreciated.

Comment: are you sure that the htaccess is working? because for me it sounds like the server is not routing your requests

Comment: I am sure because I have tested it on local machin but what I am not sure of if server's mod_rewrite is enabled..I'm not so sure X_X.. And also The 404 not found issues were not generated by my app but generated by apache .. however the root url are working.

Comment: of course the root is working, because this is the standard server action, and also the standard Yii route. I am sure you htaccess is not wokring on the server, or as you say mod_rerite is not enabled. Check with your server admin, check/requesst your server logs, otherwise nobody can help

Comment: Well I have tried to comment out the urlManager and have deleted htaccess but the result is A blank all white page even on root url.

Comment: blank page will mean, that there is an error and you do not have errors displayed. of course you could go without the url manager, check the tutorials for that. But first I would contact the Admin, so you know what the problem is.. guessing is not helping

Comment: I see .. Thanx alot for giving me response ..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem, my controller name was UserManagementController, it worked just fine on Windows, but when I moved it to Linux, I received the error "Unable to resolve the request 'usermanagement'. ".

The problem was that Linux is case-sensitive. I changed the controller name from UserManagementController to UsermanagementController and it worked.